# Is it possible to add shipping tracking number for different product in magento?

Tags: magento

I would like know
Suppose, A order consist of three product. When i submit this product to warehouse it ship the prodduct in different shipping method.

I would like to know how can i add these tracking number in magento either programmatic php or directly using mysql query

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without having to run any code (i.e PHP or MySQL), simply partially invoice the order by navigating to the order itself, choosing the invoice tab & checking / unchecking the appropriate products. Then, when you choose to create a shipment, you can base it off of an invoice number and assign appropriate tracking information to it.

Comment: But i need it to be automated.

Comment: You'll need to go into a little more detail then.